# readonly modifier

Tags: c#, .net

can we use readonly to modify property? If not, why?

Comment: because its readonly.

Comment: @RPM1984: LOL you can't use `readonly` to modify a property. Why? because it's readonly, which can't be modified. I found polysemy in English is also very funny, while in the past I only think Chinese is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need readonly for properties. If they're readonly, don't declare a setter. If you're using auto-properties, declare the setter as private.

Answer (score 4):

To create a read only property just make the setter private. If you want the property also to be read only from within the class, then remove the setter and return a read-only member.

The `readonly` keyword can only be applied to fields. That is the only usage foreseen by the C# specification at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question 'can you modify a readonly field', then your answer is YES.

However, like previous replies have stated Properties are equivalent to methods, so readonly doesnt apply.